# Как удалить все объекты и строки содержащие ключевое слово?

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня используется api facebook, теперь я хочу удалить такую возможность, в поиске естественно на это слово выходит очень большое кол-во, как удалить все разом?

Comment: Откатиться на коммит в котором этого ещё нет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, получил исходники уже с ними

Comment: Если под "удалить" подразумевается отказ от использование facebook sdk, которое подключено как ```dependency```, то берете и удаляете эту зависимость из проекта. После этого при сборке проекта появится множество ошибок, связанных с отсутствием классов, которые вы по своему усмотрению исправляете - либо удаляете этот код, либо как-то его исправляете.